# Characterization of NFA whose equivalent (minimal) DFA has exponential number of states

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata, nondeterminism

(I don't know if there are standard names for this, so) Let's say that a Nondeterministic Finite Automaton (NFA) is *$n$-expansive* if it has $n$ states and any Deterministic Finite Automaton (DFA) recognizing the same language has at least $2^{n/2}$ states.

Let $E_n$ be the set of all *$n$-expansive* NFAs.

Is there a characterization to $E_n$?

Given any NFA $A$, is there a way to test if $A \in E_n$ in polynomial time in $n$ (therefore, without constructing the minimal DFA of $A$)?

---

The lower bound $2^{n/2}$ is arbitrary. If you know a characterization for other similar exponential bounds (e.g. $2^{n-1}$ or $2^{n/10}$), it will be very helpful.

Comment: That definition isn't workable because for any NFA $n$ is fixed, and so is $2^n$. Any constant $c$ is $\Theta(2^c)$ (or $\Theta(c')$ for any other constant $c'$). You could try to characterise a family of NFAs of different sizes, where the expansive predicate applies to the family as a sequence (without $n$ qualification) but that's not really the same.

Comment: @rici I see what you mean. However, I don't have a family of NFA in mind. I just would like to know if given a NFA, there is some way to test if it will blow up when determinized and if there is a way to characterize the NFAs that blow up, do you understand? Maybe I can replace the asymptotic lower bound by a somehow arbitrary but still representative one... I will edit the question. Thank you for commenting.

Comment: i understand your desire, but it's really not well-defined. Say you have a 10-state NFA. What's the smallest number of states in the DFA which would qualify as exponential? 100? 200? 500? Even a 2-state DFA could be exponential if the NFA has some characteristic which guarantees at least $2^{n-9}$ DFA states.

Comment: By the way, if this is a practical rather than theoretical problem, you might be interested in this one. Let $\mu$ be an ordered list of a subset of $\Sigma$. A sentence in $\Sigma^*$ is $\mu$-complete if it contains all the symbols in $\mu$. The language of $\mu$ complete sentences is regular, and can be described by the regular expression which is the union over all permutations of $\mu$ of $\Sigma\pi_1\Sigma...\pi_k\Sigma$ (where $\pi$ is a permutation). The NFA then has $O(k\; k!)$ states and the determinized DFA is subject to exponential blowup, with the standard algorithm...

Comment: So that's totally impractical for even small values of $k=|\mu|$. (The original for this problem is "words containing all vowels", where $k$ is five. The regex above blows flex up.) However, the minimised DFA "only" has $2^k$ states, which is 32 in the case of $k=5$. The question is: how to handle such regular expressions without generating the $2^{k\;k!}$-state intermediate DFA?

Comment: ... there's an alternative regular expression which doesn't blow up, but that's not the point. Casual users will write or autogenerate the simple regex, and that's what the tool needs to deal with. (F)lex doesn't handle it.

Comment: Damn, too late to edit. The regex in the above comment should have $\Sigma^*$ throughout instead of $\Sigma$.